# SQL database management

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently having issues with my database. It shows this error:

> Msg 1911, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Column name 'suffix_desc' does not exist in the target table or view.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

This is the code,

```
create table prefix 
(
    prefix_desc        varchar(4) not null,
    primary key (prefix_desc)
) 

create table suffix 
(
     suffix_desc        varchar(4)    not null,
     primary key (suffix_desc)
)

create table member
(
      member_id      varchar(80) not null,
      First_name     varchar(50) not null,
      Last_name      varchar(50) not null,
      middle_name    varchar(50) null,
      Dob            date        not null,
      Email          varchar(80) not null,
      UserID         varchar(80) null,
      Password       varchar(16) not null,
      phone_friendly_ind  varchar(3) not null, 
      SMS_ind        varchar(3) not null,
      return_ind        varchar(3) not null,
      fuel_prepay_ind   varchar(3) not null,
      post_mail_ind     varchar(3) not null,
      email_ind         varchar(3) not null,
      privacy_ind       varchar(3) not null,

      primary key (member_id, suffix_desc, prefix_desc),

      foreign key (suffix_desc) references suffix (suffix_desc),
      foreign key (prefix_desc) references prefix (prefix_desc)
)
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. There is no column in the "member" table called suffix_desc. You can't create a constraint (PK, FK or otherwise) on a column that does not exist.

Comment: the title is irrelevant with details of question

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add this :

```
create table member(
   ...
   suffix_desc varchar(4) not null,
   prefix_desc varchar(4) not null,
   ...
)
```

Comment: Hi, i don't understand why do i need to add suffix_desc and prefix_desc when i've created a table for it? In my EERD diagram, under Member entity, the attributes are just first name......privarcy indicator. So i'm merely following what it says. Do u mind telling me why do u have to add suffix and prefix?

Comment: You need to learn relational database first. I will explain it as simple I can. Imagine table `prefix`, `suffix`, and `member` have field `id`. And `member` have one-to-one relation to `prefix` and `suffix` connected by `id`. You must create `suffix_id` and `prefix_id` in order `member` know `suffix_id` and `prefix_id`

Comment: @AgnesLam In member you don't have `suffix_desc` and `prefix_desc` columns then how will you be able create foreign key for the column that doesnot exists

Comment: Let me make more simple, Imagine `id` as your address, telephone or any identity and you want to make connection with new friends. You need to give your `id` to your friends and your friends need to save it in order to contact you in future.

Comment: @NoDisplayName : again, you are so fast bro ;(

Comment: @ColourDalnet You are the one who answered not me :) Its just a comment after 40 odd mins

Comment: Actually you can answer it, I saw you edit it 3 minutes before me ;(

Comment: i'm so sorry, but this is the last few doubts i want to clear.. 'Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'member' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__license__member___300424B4'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.' may i know what does it means?

Comment: Looks, I even drawing something for you ;) http://prntscr.com/5waix6 
Let make it more excited, you give me your id as foreign key, and I will save it to contact you in future as my foreign key. That's called a database relationship. ;)

Comment: THANKS!

However, is there anything wrong with this..?

Comment: Create table Phone_fax
(member_id  varchar(80) not null,
country_code  varchar(4)  not null,
Tel_number  integer  not null,
Tel_type  varchar(4) not null,
Pref_phone_ind varchar(3) not null,
Primary key (tel_number, member_id, country_code),
foreign key (member_id) references member (member_id),
Foreign key (country_code) references country (country_code)
)

Comment: You can not ask new questions in comments. Please check it yourself and if found any errors create a new question. Mark as Answer if this is the solution for your current problem. Read this before asking new question again http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask